# Error when trying to put a attribute of an object to logger, NLog

Tags: c#, nlog

When I'm trying to put a application log to see the attributes of the object with NLog, it gives me error as

```
_logger.Info("token :{0}, Object:{1}", "token", Object.Select(y => new { y.Id, y.Name, y.Charge}));
```

This display error "System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator".

Then I tried to convert this to List as:

```
_logger.Info("token :{0}, Object:{1}", "token", Object.Select(y => new { y.Id, y.Name, y.Charge}).ToList());
```

Then error displayed as "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType1]".

I cant seem to log this object. any help?

Comment: You haven't told us what the actual error message says!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to *stringify* object you can use `@` to

```
_logger.Info("token :{0}, Object:{@1}", "token", Object.Select(y => new { y.Id, y.Name, y.Charge}).ToList());
```

However I'd suggest to switch to structured logging: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging

```
_logger.Info("token :{token}, Object:{object}", "token", Object.Select(y => new { y.Id, y.Name, y.Charge}));
```

According to above documentation it should properly *render* collection of anonymous objects. Otherwise you can just add `@` to serialize object to JSON representation.